# Multiple Resource Bundle in faces-config.xml in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, properties-file, resourcebundle, faces-config

How to define multiple resource bundle in faces-config.xml in jsf 2.0 ?
I have searched on various blogposts but every post talks about using only one resource bundle. 
I am new to JSF .Any help on any resource would be of great help.

Comment: So you tried adding multiple `<resource-bundle>...</resource-bundle>`  in faces-config.xml and it failed to work?

Comment: Yes I tried but it doesn't have any effect.Its not loading my bundle.

Comment: Maybe ask a specific question about that then with code in [mcve] flavour